# Firefox is not rendering some icons; Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firefox, rendering

My flutter web app is not rendering some icons on firefox browser only that too in windows only. In Linux its fine, chrome is also fine for all OS. I'm using material icons only. But the consoles shows the following error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNeRT.png)

Happens always in firefox windows